# using matplotlib to plot excel data and csv file together

Tags: matplotlib

I have a Timeseries data for leaks which is a csv file and I have another excel file which have date when the leak has occured. I want to plot this on same graph for visulaization and to point when leak has occured. I am not able to plot this on same graph using matplotlib. Can someone help me with this. I am using python programming.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
rows = 3
cols = 4
fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(30,10))
df.plot(ax=axes, rot=60)
```

I was trying to use the above matplot lib code to plot.

[This one is the Timeseries data which i have from the database for sensors.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKZYM.png)

[This image has date on which leak has occured.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bd44W.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I place a table on a plot in Matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524401/how-can-i-place-a-table-on-a-plot-in-matplotlib)

Comment: Or side by side [Plot table along chart using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53573121/plot-table-along-chart-using-matplotlib)